# .NET Core some characters are displayed as question mark

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, encoding, asp.net-core

I am trying to display some of Czech characters líke ř, á, í etc but the .net displays question mark instead. I dont have a clue why. I have set meta charset in the layout.cshtml. 
[image: Screenshot of one page]

Comment: Did you specify `UTF-8` and is your cshtml file encoded in `UTF-8` as well?

Comment: I am not sure how I can accomplish that in .Net core

Comment: Can you share your layout meta charset code?
And to check file's encoding you can open the file in Notepad++ and check Encoding from the top menu.
One more thing - check what encoding Internet browser is using..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I've fixed it by File->Save As->In the arrow next to the Save Button selected Save with encoding and saved as UTF-8. I still dont know why Visual Studio makes encoding for Views "Windows" as default. Curious to know, how to change it.